# How to bind a ComboBox to a string value in WPF without using ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that in read-only mode is used to just display a single value (string) and becomes disabled, this is the current implementation:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSalesDocuments" SelectedValuePath="SalesDocumentId" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SalesDocumentId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesDocumentAName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

in this mode I'm not going to bind it with the same object as the write-mode object, but bound to a more lighter object that contains a string property `SalesDocumentAName`. The problem is that I can't set the Displayed and Selected value to that property without using the `ItemsSource` collection that needs an `IEnumerable` object.

Comment: If you cannot select anything why do you want a combobox at all?

Comment: I want to keep the same UI controls in both modes

Comment: What is wrong with using ItemsSource if e;g. you use a list of the 'lighter' objects? It would be helpfull if you stated the problem more clearly...

Comment: The ComboBox has a Text property. Bind to that

Comment: In sort you cannot bind `string` to `ComboBox ` you must use `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `IValueConverter` to get a collection from a single item

```
public class ObjectToCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = new List<object>();
        if (value != null)
        {
            collection.Add(value);
        }
        return collection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the `ComboBox` with

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SalesDocumentAName,Converter={StaticResource ObjectToCollectionConverter}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SalesDocumentAName, Mode=OneWay}" 
    IsReadOnly="true"/>
```

Comment: How to set it in code.. please see my edited question.

Comment: Then bind it to the object that has the SalesDocumentAName property. Your original code has not enough information about that, but you should get the concept

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a `ComboBox` to a `string` value. The `ItemsSource` property can only be bound to an `IEnumerable`. You could remove all items but one `string` from the `IEnumerable` though.

The other option would be to use another Control or modify the `ControlTemplate`. A `ComboBox` is not a `TextBlock`, unless you make it look like one.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't set ItemsSource, you can add a ComboBoxItem with Content set to light-weight object:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSalesDocuments" SelectedValuePath="SalesDocumentId" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SalesDocumentId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesDocumentAName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=SalesDocument}" 
                      ContentTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, ElementName=cmbSalesDocuments}"/>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

note: ItemsSource or Items - only one property can be used at a time

Comment: There is no need to define an ItemTemplate then.